# Minimum arguments to draw a line segment

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, optimization

To draw a line segment in a 2d plane, you'd need two points (x, y) or 4 numbers. There are other alternatives to two points such as one point, segment length and and angle (relative to x axis).

I am wondering if there is any way of drawing any arbitrary line segment with less than 4 parameters? I am not concerned about the drawing efficiency of the solution. Purely interested in reducing the number of parameters. Of course predefined/global values can be used.

Is there a field in Mathematics (or even a good search keyword I can use) that focuses on optimising spatial complexity of arguments such as this (e.g Can a rectangle be drawn with less than 5 parameters)?

First post on here, sorry if question is not worded properly or formatting is subpar.

Comment: @stevengregory The OP seems to be considering line segments, not lines.

Comment: @angryavian thanks. Edited

Comment: In principle you can use a single real number and pack all the parameters into its digits. For example if the two endpoints are $(p,q)$ and $(r,s)$ with digits $0.p_1p_2p_3\dots$ and so on, then you can use the parameter $0.p_1q_1r_1s_1p_2q_2r_2s_2p_3q_3r_3s_3\dots$

Comment: For a rectangle, 3 points re enough since you can always ''mirror'' the 4th point from the 3rd